# Is there a way to add a scroll bar to dfSummary output in R markdown file?

Tags: r, r-markdown, summarytools

I've already tried using the `print` function:

```
print(dfSummary(df), method = "render")
```

And also all the solutions [here](https://github.com/dcomtois/summarytools/issues/59) but they don't seem to work with `html_document` as the output file type of the R Markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, Inês

The answer is in provided link. You just need to add `max.tbl.height` argument and specify height in pixels:

```
print(dfSummary(df),
      max.tbl.height = 250,
      method = "render")
```

Here goes an reproducible example (see `# comments` for tips & tricks):

````
---
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
date: "26/05/2020"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: TRUE
    toc_float: TRUE
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(summarytools)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(results = "asis")
```

### Adding a scrollbar to dfSummary

```{r summarytools-css, echo = FALSE}
# with summarytools’ CSS we can cancel Bootstrap’s CSS (both are included by default)
# without it odd layout are expected, especially with dfSummary()
st_css(bootstrap = FALSE)
```

```{r dfSummary, echo = FALSE}
print(dfSummary(tobacco, 
                style = "grid",           # set style to “grid”
                valid.col = FALSE,        # drop Valid column if redundant
                graph.magnif = 0.82),     # zoom factor (max = 1) for bar plots and histograms
      headings = FALSE,
      footnote = NA,
      # use maximum table (specified) height (in pixels) and wrap the results in a scrollable window
      max.tbl.height = 300,            
      method = "render")
```
````

[image]

If you have interest, check out Dominic's [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/summarytools/vignettes/Recommendations-rmarkdown.html) - "Recommendations for Using summarytools With Rmarkdown".

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the response. 
I chose to select a number of pages to only show 5 entries at a time, using `DT::datatable()`.
The problem with `print()` is that it was putting the table window larger than the page width.

But many thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest using the package "DT", if you absolutely need dfSummary I can try again, but would need the minimal amount of code for replicate your example. DT has search functionality along with letting the user control how many rows they see when viewing the data.

````
  ---
  title: "DF summary"
  author: "stackoverflow"
  date: "5/24/2020"
  output: html_document
  ---
  ```{r}
  library(DT)
  datatable(head(mtcars, 30), options = list(
  order = list(list(2, 'asc'), list(4, 'desc'))
  ))
  ```
````